# Drop rest of data in specific condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe such as:

```
A       B       C
27.00   9.90    6.24899992
18.00   6.90    4.827007354
15.00   4.20    2.252776065
7.50    2.90    1.673376053
3.00    3.50    3.233439065
4.00    1.20    4.254737365
3.00    2.30    1.257349325
0       8.90    0.254932365
1.00    0.90    2.233293435
```

now If Column A have 0, I want to drop rest of data in Column B and C from 5 previous row to the bottom row like this:

```
A       B       C
27.00   9.90    6.24899992
18.00   6.90    4.827007354
15.00   NaN     NaN
7.50    NaN     NaN
3.00    NaN     NaN
4.00    NaN     NaN
3.00    NaN     NaN
0       NaN     NaN
1.00    NaN     NaN
```

Another example of my dataframe:

```
A       B       C
27.00   9.90    6.24899992
18.00   6.90    4.827007354
15.00   4.20    2.252776065
7.50    2.90    1.673376053
3.00    NaN     NaN
4.00    NaN     NaN
3.00    NaN     NaN
2.80    NaN     NaN
1.00    NaN     NaN
```

and The result that I want is just same data because it have not 0 in column A like below:

```
A       B       C
27.00   9.90    6.24899992
18.00   6.90    4.827007354
15.00   4.20    2.252776065
7.50    2.90    1.673376053
3.00    NaN     NaN
4.00    NaN     NaN
3.00    NaN     NaN
2.80    NaN     NaN
1.00    NaN     NaN
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: There is only one `0` value in colum `A` ?

Comment: Nono. They can have many 0 value depending on data.

Comment: hmmm, so you need 5 rows before first `0` ? And all rows by first 0 are NaNs ?

Comment: I just do not need rows from 5 row before first 0 to bottom row. and I need rest of rows.

Comment: hmmm, in new data is no `0` value in column `A`, it is typo or not?

Comment: Oh..nono It is float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want set 5 values before first `0` and then all values after first 0 to `NaN`s in columns `B` and `C` use:

```
N = 5
m = df['A'] == 0

idx = next(iter(m.index[m]), df.index[-1] + 1)
print (idx)
2

#if possible less like N rows before first 0 add max
first = max(idx - N, 0)
print (first)
7

df.iloc[first:, df.columns.get_indexer(['B','C'])] = np.nan
print (df)
      A    B         C
0  27.0  9.9  6.249000
1  18.0  6.9  4.827007
2  15.0  NaN       NaN
3   7.5  NaN       NaN
4   3.0  NaN       NaN
5   4.0  NaN       NaN
6   3.0  NaN       NaN
7   0.0  NaN       NaN
8   1.0  NaN       NaN
```

---

If no value `0` in column `A`:

```
N = 5
m = df['A'] == 0

idx = next(iter(m.index[m]), df.index[-1] + 1)
print (idx)
9

#if possible less like N rows before first 0 add max
first = max(idx - N, 0)
print (first)
4

df.iloc[first:, df.columns.get_indexer(['B','C'])] = np.nan
print (df)
      A    B         C
0  27.0  9.9  6.249000
1  18.0  6.9  4.827007
2  15.0  4.2  2.252776
3   7.5  2.9  1.673376
4   3.0  NaN       NaN
5   4.0  NaN       NaN
6   3.0  NaN       NaN
7  10.0  NaN       NaN
8   1.0  NaN       NaN
```

---

First solution:

```
#create mask
m = df['A'] == 0

#cumulative sum of mask - return Trues for all values after first 0
m1 = m.cumsum() > 0
#counter of values above 0 with swapping order by indexing [::-1] and cumulative sum
s = m.iloc[::-1].cumsum()
#create counter and compare by 5
m2 = s.groupby(s).cumcount() < 5
#chain masks by | for bitwise OR
mask = m1 | m2.sort_index()

#set NaNs by mask
df[['B','C']] = df[['B','C']].mask(mask)
print (df)
```

Comment: @jezrael out of curiosity, you wouldn't need m1 since all below rows would have cumcount of 0 in m2 and so, would be included anyway, right?

Comment: @MonoNeuElogy - I think is necessary change `first = max(idx - N + 1, 0)` to `first = max(idx - N, 0)`

Comment: I'll simplify my examples on my question. Please wait.

Comment: @MonoNeuElogy - tested and working my solution nice. But one thing - are index values default - maybe help `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` before my solution

Comment: Which solution? First one or Second one?

Comment: Does not exist united solution in any situation such as first solution?

Comment: @MonoNeuElogy - hmmm, I prefer more solution with `idx` and `first`, because more simply. But not working for you? Not select 4 rows before first 0 ?

Comment: I want united code for any situation whether they have `0` or not. But your solution is not working in both situation, working in only one situation.

Comment: @MonoNeuElogy - hmmm, so first or second paragraph of code in asnwer or third or fourth paragraph in my solution is like you need and only not working in real data?

Comment: I use `for` loop, so I have many dataframe that have `0` or not, But I need one code that can use in any situation. One of your solution is working in dataframe have `0`, But not working in dataframe have not `0`. But the others of your solution is working in in dataframe have not `0`, But not working in dataframe have `0`.

Comment: @MonoNeuElogy - hmmm, problem is in real data, solutions 1,2,3,4 paragraph working nice with sample data in my answer? Can you be more specific why not working? Because now I am lost if my solutions working with sample data from question or not.

Comment: hmmm, The result that I want is just like 1, 4 paragraph. But The codes of 1, 4 paragraph are different.

Comment: @MonoNeuElogy - OK, answer was edited, 1, 2. paragraph.